# Dynamic list view creator - Working with the 5k View limit

Tags: list, list-view, resource-throttling

I am looking for some ideas/experiences people have had working with the 5k view throttling .

Outcome I am trying to achieve: users can search for documents in a particular document library by filling in a form. Form will have drop down fields containing the available filter/metadata options for this Library.
The idea is to have a form to create a query/view. This form will have drop down boxes. The value for the drop down boxes will be obtained dynamically from the library - unique values from key columns.

User would select values in the drop down boxes, press search, then a view of the library will be displayed, filtered based on the values selected in the form.

What happens after the form is filled out and a user selects "Search" is where i am unsure; 
If the list had <5k items, I could build a URL that filters the default (All Documents View) e.g. FilterField1=DocumentType&FilterValue1=Contract&FilterField2=Status&FilterValue2=Pending

I could dynamically create CAML query based on values from the form. Then present the results in a custom page - that would exactly replicates a OOTB library - column filtering, etc.?

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

I think your second idea would be the most efficient.  You would not want to have a ton of views in your dropdowns when people create them.  Also, if someone does not delete the view correctly, or if for some reason the view does not create correctly, you can corrupt the list.

Make a dynamic table with jQuery in a CEWP using SPServices or CSOM. This way it will not tax your list as well; plus it will look really nice :)

Comment: I appreciate the response. Do you have any further suggestions on creating the results tables i.e. providing the standard doc lib functionality; edit properties, deleted, check in/out, quick edit view - basically the OOTB doc lib ribbon and the standard (...) options.

Comment: You could create a DataViewWebPart which would give you this functionality.  You can also create filters for the data you want to have present in the fields through the DVWP as well.  I am not sure about check in and check out on the DVWP.  It is what it is titled, a view of the data.  I do know that you can put edit/create/delete controls on it.  To get the documents, you might need to use a soap call so you can get the absolute URI of the documents.  On the surface (programmatically), documents/attachments come as a Boolean response.  There are a few ways to try to get your result.